# Links to questions on metas of closed sites should redirect to the Area 51 proposal (for the main site)

Tags: feature-request, area-51, per-site-meta, redirection, closed-sites

If you click on a link to a question that was on a site that is now closed, you get redirected to the Area 51 proposal page for that site - for example, [Why is the timeline of Catch-22 all messed up?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/why-is-the-timeline-of-catch-22-all-messed-up), which takes you to [the proposal page for Literature](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature).

If, however, you click on a link to a question that was on the *meta site* for a site that is now closed, you get a 404 at A51 - for example, [Theoretical Physics is closing](http://meta.theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions/245/theoretical-physics-is-closing), which takes you to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/meta.theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com, which is a "page not found" page. Ideally, this would instead go to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com, which will then redirect you to [the proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics).

EDIT (18 Apr 2016): The behavior of links to questions on closed sites seems to have changed since I posted this question in 2014. The above link to "Why is the timeline of Catch-22 all messed up?" now just goes to a standard "Site not found: literature.stackexchange.com" error page, where previously it used to send you to the A51 proposal. So now, the behavior of meta links and main links to questions on closed sites are the same, in that they're both broken. (?)

Comment: Now that there's a new Literature site, yet another ugly part of the system is visible: instead of being taken to a panda 404 page, you are taken to a completely unrelated question/answer/tag wiki on the *new* Literature site.

Comment: Related: [Following meta link from question on closed site → Error 404](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266299/335251) – It looks like this was reported there in 2015 and fixed, but that was back when meta URLs looked like `meta.[sitename].stackexchange.com`. I'm guessing that the shift to the `[sitename].meta.stackexchange.com` URL format may have caused a regression...?

Comment: Regarding your 2016 edit, I think that redirect has just been removed entirely (as have many/most of the redirects from older sites that have long since closed).

Comment: @V2Blast The redirect to the corresponding Area 51 proposal only works for so long as the old site is still in the database. At some point in 2015-2016, the team started removing those databases after a period, which would break the redirect and make it go to the site not found page instead. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370774. Per that post, the redirect only works for one closed site, and it's because its database wasn't removed for some reason, and the staff member was able to access the actual site due to their staff privileges.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Ah right, thanks for the explanation on that :)

Comment: @V2Blast The regression is still in effect for that one site, plus the since-closed Windows Phone and any future closed sites (i.e., closed sites where the database hasn't been removed).