# Following meta link from question on closed site → Error 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, broken-link, closed-sites

As a user on Academia, I can follow the link to the original questions migrated from the [failed Open Science site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65426/open-science), such as [this question](http://openscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-protect-scientific-open-research-from-being-patented?noredirect=1).  From there, I can click through to the main Open Science page, and I'm redirected to area51.  However, if I go to Help → Meta, I get an [Error 404, Page not found](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/meta.openscience.stackexchange.com) — the system is trying to lookup the Open Science *Meta* on area51 which, naturally, does not exist.

Comment: Any user can follow migrated question back to its parent site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Right.  My 10k privilege is that I can easily get an overview of all those migrated questions.

Comment: Related: [Links to questions on metas of closed sites should redirect to the Area 51 proposal (for the main site)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232330/335251)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed as of build 374 (Area 51 only). Basically `/proposals/lookup` will strip off `meta.` from the front of the host name before the lookup happens.

Comment: The build is already 375, did it jump by 2, or was it fixed a while ago?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It jumped by 2, for reasons I don't understand. :-P

Comment: lol, well, it's Area 51. Weird things happen in there. :-)