# Most links to old, closed Stack Exchange sites don't redirect to their Area 51 proposals anymore

Tags: feature-request, bug, area-51, redirection, closed-sites

A while ago, old links to Stack Exchange beta sites that were closed would redirect back to their Area 51 proposal, which would serve to inform users that the site didn't have enough activity during its beta and had been closed.

However, I tested this out today, and for almost every site I tested, this doesn't work anymore: such old links now go to a generic [site not found](//stackexchange.com/site-not-found) page, rather than to the Area 51 proposal as they used to. Some of the sites I tested are [Personal Productivity](//productivity.stackexchange.com), [SmugMug](//smugmug.stackexchange.com), and [Arabic Language](//arabic.stackexchange.com). The only closed site I tested where the redirect still works today is [Augur](//augur.stackexchange.com). (I skipped testing sites that were closed down in private beta.)

Can this please be fixed to restore the prior redirects? I think it's important to display a message to external users following links outside our network to these sites that the site was closed, rather than just directing them to a generic "site not found" page. It's also important to let users know that their prior contributions have not been permanently removed and provide them a link to download the data dump.

Comment: Is there any reference anywhere that indicates these redirects were supposed to be _permanent_? I was not under the impression they were, and that the redirect would disappear whenever that site's database was actually removed (e.g., as staff, when I visit the Augur URL, I see the _actual site_ because the database still exists, for whatever reason).

Comment: @animuson I think I saw it on the blog somewhere. If it's not, or if the team's position has changed since the blog post was put out, then this is a feature request to reinstate the prior redirects even if the databases have been removed, for the reasons in the last paragraph.

Comment: I don't believe our position ever changed on it. The technical limitation there is that it only detects URLs for site databases that still exist. So once the database is gone, so is the redirect. Most of these redirects have not existed for _years_ and nobody has even noticed. E.g. the last time Web Archive recorded an Area 51 redirect for Productivity was back in June of 2018.

Comment: If you go to https://augur.stackexchange.com/users/login while logged out you can actually see the login page for the site.