# When an SE site is closed, redirect the dead URLs to Area 51 instead of 404s

Tags: feature-request, link-rot, closed-sites

Example: https://productivity.stackexchange.com/ was closed. It'd be better if it redirects to https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity instead of some 404 message, so that visitors can be informed of the closure and access data dump ([if available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267415/178179)).

Comment: Already requested: [Most links to old, closed Stack Exchange sites don't redirect to their Area 51 proposals anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370774/most-links-to-old-closed-stack-exchange-sites-dont-redirect-to-their-area-51-p). Per the staff comments, in order for a redirect to work the site's database has to continue existing, and once they delete the database the system will no longer recognize the site URL at all. I hope they get around to implementing a way to redirect while still allowing them to delete the database.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks, turned out I had upvoted your question sometime in the past.

Comment: "closed after 2449 days in beta" - how long are beta stages *intended* to last???

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that's one reason why SE should [freeze the website (= keep it online but make it read-only) instead of only archiving it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384353/178179).